# osmosis --read-xml fails in combination with mapwriter plugin

Tags: java, windows, openstreetmap, osmosis

I have a problem with Osmosis v 0.43 with mapsforge mapwriter plugin 0.3.0. on Windows. A command

```
osmosis --read-xml file=C:\geo\testmap.osm --mw file=C:\geo\genmap.map
bbox=0.0,0.0,51.9,19.2
```

fails with error:

```
SEVERE: Thread for task 1-rx failed
java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
org.mapsforge.map.writer.osmosis.MapFileWriterTask.initialize(Ljava/util/Map;)V
at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.xml.v0_6.XmlReader.run(XmlReader.java:95)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried using --rx with --wx and obtained no errors, so something must be wrong with the mapwriter plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer: it turned out that mapwriter plugin 0.3.0 was not compatible with the newest Osmosis version, so downgrading the tool to 0.40.1 worked